# Update slider value

Tags: ios

I have 2 ViewControllers, ViewController_A and ViewController_B. ViewController_A had a slider with a doSlider method as follow.

```
- (void)doSlider:(float)value{
  [viewController_B getValue:[slider_1 value]];
}
```

ViewController_B had a getValue method as follow.

```
- (void)getValue:(float)value{
  width = value;
  NSLog(@"getValue %f", width);
}
```

When I drag the slider in ViewController_A, ViewController_B will print out width value. But it seems only available inside getValue method. May I pass width value to other method in ViewController_B, for example, touchesMoved. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you make `width` a property of viewController_B. Actually, it looks to me like that is what you are doing, but perhaps I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Once you get the slider value with `[slider_1 value]` you can use it any way you please.  When you pass the value to `getValue:` and assign to `width` you can then use `width` as you please.

Comment: I used "width" to set brush size in touchesMoved, but it was always zero. How to pass "width" to touchesMoved?

Comment: `touchesMoved:withEvent` doesn't have much to do with a `double` number.  It must be your code related to passing argument to `touchesMoved:withEvent` that is to blame.

Comment: Do you mean it is impossible to pass argument to touchesMoved?

Comment: No, it certainly is not impossible.  But, the arguments are `NSSet` and `NSEvent` - which are not related to `double.  So, at the least, you'll need to package up your `double` in some way.

Comment: If I return getValue's width value, is it possible to set the brush size in touchesMoved? What about delegate or @protocol?

Comment: This is a separate question.  Mark this question answered and then post another question.  From your above comment it is not clear what classes and methods are related to `brush size`

Comment: In touchesMoved as follow:     CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), width ); "width" is stroke width.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what touchesMoved has to do with brush size nor CGContextSetLineWidth().  But, as I said, you can use `width` from `getValue:` any way you please.